# Extracting data from XML using SimpleXML, third-level

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to extract data from an xml file. The problem is I know how to do the second level, but not a third level.

Here's a sample test of the XML

```
<createacct>
  <result>
    <options>
     <ns></ns>
    </options>
    <rawout>
    stuff
    </rawout>
    <status>1</status>
    <statusmsg>success</statusmsg>
  </result>
</createacct>
```

Now, how would I extract the data from:  `<rawout>`, `<status>` and `<statusmsg>`? I may need to look at `<result><options><ns>` as well.

I suppose maybe:

```
$yop = new SimpleXMLElement ($xmlFile);
$rawout = array((string) $yop->rawout); // for rawout
```

and so forth for `<status>` and `<statusmsg>`. But what for `<result><options><ns>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this does the trick:

```
$xml->result[0]->options->ns
```

Comment: I thought so - but I doubted it.