# How do I extract values from this xml object?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (3) { 
["@attributes"]=> array(1) { 
   ["responsecode"]=> string(3) "200" 
} 
["nextpage"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) { 
} 
["resultset_web"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) { 
   ["@attributes"]=> array(4) { 
      ["count"]=> string(2) "10" 
      ["start"]=> string(1) "0" 
      ["totalhits"]=> string(8) "22497060" 
      ["deephits"]=> string(8) "23000000" 
   } 
   ["result"]=> array(10) { 
      [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (7) { 
         ["abstract"]=> string(110) "MSN's all-in-one Internet portal, the home of Hotmail, MSN Messenger, MSNBC News, Encarta, and Slate Magazine." 
         ["clickurl"]=> string(360) "http://teqpad.com/www/msn.com" 
         ["date"]=> string(10) "2011/01/14" 
         ["dispurl"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (0) { 
         } 
         ["size"]=> string(5) "82136" 
         ["title"]=> string(3) "MSN" 
         ["url"]=> string(19) "http://www.msn.com/" 
      }
```

I want to extract value of `title` and `abstract` from above xml using php.

Comment: Well, firstly.. that's not XML.

Comment: *(examples)* http://de2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: seems as though the xml is already parsed by SimpleXML

Comment: This question is a duplicate of almost any of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extract+simplexml

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting data from XML using SimpleXML, third-level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484516/extracting-data-from-xml-using-simplexml-third-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already parsed it with SimpleXML, what you really want to do is traverse through your object and find the values of `title` and `abstract`.

If your object is `$xml`, `$xml->resultset_web->result[0]->abstract` contains `abstract` while
`$xml->resultset_web->result[0]->title` contains `title` for one value. For all the values,

```
foreach ($xml->resultset_web->result as $v) {
  $title = $v->title;
  $abstract = $v->title;
}
```

Comment: you are right it was loaded by simplexml_load_string....sorry it was my mistake..

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you have about 10 titles to extract by judging from this:

```
["result"]=> array(10) {
```

The way of doing this would be:

```
foreach ($simpleXML->resultset_web->result as $result) {
    $title = $result->title;
    $abstract = $result->abstract;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that would work, you have to use the children() method ($simpleXML->resultset_web->result->children()). The simplexml object has some unexpected behaviour, I learned the hard way.

Comment: @Naatan: No, this will work. The XML is formatted like `<result><title>...</title></result><result><title>...</title></result>` according to the dump.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a var_dump of a var that holds a SimpleXML object.
So let's say that you have something like this:

```
//$data i a string containing your XML
$xmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
```

then you should be able to access the items like this:

```
foreach ($xmlobj->resultset_web->result as $result) {
    echo $result->abstract;
    echo $result->title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all nodes with path resultset_web -> result -> title:

```
$xml = [your object];
$allTitlesAsArray = $xml->xpath('/resultset_web/result/title');
$allAbstractAsArray = $xml->xpath('/resultset_web/result/abstract');
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should work :

```
$ob->resultset_web->result[0]->title;
```

As said, just read up on the php simplexml documentation. And note that not each case will be this simple, if you have multiple results you will have to iterate through the children with the children() method, you can't access them directly as I did above.